# Should I still be hoping up on something which is impossible to happen?

Tags: belief, dream, destiny, blessings-of-allah

Assalamualaikum, this is a question I was so longing to ask.Should we ask Allah something/for something even after knowing that it is not possible to happen in a worldly way and I know that there is almost or is zero possibility for my wish to be granted by Allah? I mean, is hoping for something impossible to happen invalidated?

Comment: Is it possible to explain what exactly you want? Also Allah knows when and what duas you will make as everything is predetermined and its up to Allah to decide whether you will get a reward or not.

Comment: It seems to me that there's a slight possibility for the thing to happen given your description. In this case, you should have at least a bit of hope. Something impossible would be, for example, wishing a passed one to return to life. I don't think making prayers for such a thing makes a lot of sense from a religious perspective.